# are we going to get a linux module for APFS?

Tags: filesystems

ExFAT doesn't support symbolic links on linux. My git repositories are getting corrupted if I use them on exfat removable media between linux and macOS. Is there any work going on to support APFS on linux?

Comment: Until then, UDF might be a good solution for a filesystem that does support symlinks on Unix OSes and that works on Linux, OS X and even Windows. 

Have a look [here](https://github.com/JElchison/format-udf)

Comment: Yet another solution would be to experiment with ZFS, but that is going to require 3rd party extra software on all your OSes. 
Whereas UDF can be read natively by all OSes, as long as you keep using the "partition table" trick in the above-mentioned tool.

Comment: Last but not least : git is distributed. You can use multiple repositories (and you can easily sync remotely over SSH to another computer)
It could be a good idea to revise your workflow in such a way that you keep a separate copy on each computer, and sync over git+ssh between them (or to/from the computer that you consider "reference").

Comment: I shall try out UDF soon.

Comment: @DrYak your comments should really be a three-part answer! This way I can upvote you! :-)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that UDF has a 2TB disk size limit (8TB with 4K blocks).

Comment: rocking UDF past 1 month! thanks @DrYak!